# Modules installed using pip, recognised by PyCharm, but not by macOS terminal

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to access a python file created on PyCharm with my terminal. When I import modules on PyCharm they are found and successfully imported (e.g tkinter, PIL etc.). When I try to run the file on my terminal I get the following message :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "THE_project_GUI.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

The `which python` command returns : `/usr/bin/python`

The `which -a pip` command returns : `/usr/local/bin/pip`

How do make sure I use the interpreter that pip is installing for?

**Trial:**

tromgy's solution:

```
me@mahmouds-mbp-2 ~ % ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python 

me@mahmouds-mbp-2 ~ % cd /Users/me/Documents/Programming/THE_project

me@mahmouds-mbp-2 THE_project % /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python THE_project_GUI.py
```

returns:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/python", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xcf' in file /usr/local/bin/python on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

v0idbar's solution:

I have installed python 3.7 using :

```
 brew install python@3.7
```

returns :

Python has been installed as
/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/libexec/bin

```
You can install Python packages with
  /usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

I have changed the Pycharm interpreter by going to File> New project settings> Preferences for new projects. And then added 3.7 after finding it using `/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3`.

Then I ran the following :

```
me@mahmouds-mbp-2 THE_project % /usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3
/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3
Python 3.7.11 (default, Jul  6 2021, 12:43:19) 
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> /usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3 THE_project_GUI.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    /usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3 THE_project_GUI.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: macOS default python is 2.7, and you're probably using a different interpreter/virtual environment in PyCharm. You need to find out which one is used by PyCharm. If it is a virtual environment you can then use `workon <virtual-environment-name>` command in the terminal to set it up.

Comment: Could you use the built-in terminal in PyCharm?

Comment: @tromgy The interpreter used by PyCharm is Python 3.8 /usr/local/bin/python3.8. But I am not sure how to make my terminal use the same interpreter.

Comment: @bicarlsen I am not sure what you mean. I was able to import the modules and run the code successfully in PyCharm if that's what you mean.

Comment: so now you know the path, and you can just run `/usr/local/bin/python3.8 <your_python_file>` in the terminal.

Comment: @tromgy how do I do that? And how do I make it the default so I don't have to do it each time I try to run python on my terminal? To be able to just run "python filename.py" I mean.

Comment: @MahmoudHosny, you can create a symbolic link to it like this:

`ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python`

then it will be available just as `python` in the terminal. Be aware though that will "shadow" the default python 2.7.

Comment: @tromgy I have edited my question with your solution. Please have a look. Can you also clarify what you mean by it will shadow the default? I did get a message that macOS won't support python 2.7 anymore soon. Isn't there a permanent solution where I use a newer version as the default?

Comment: @MahmoudHosny, this command line you show is wrong:
`/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python THE_project_GUI.py`
-- you're trying to run the symlink file through the Python interpeter. It should be simply `python THE_project_GUI.py` instead. Your last example is also wrong, as you trying pass the shell command line into Python REPL.

Answer (score 0):

Try run `pip -V` to figure out what python version it is using:

```
$ pip -V

pip 19.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

You can check if it the same version as the python executable you are using: `python -m pip -V`

```
$ python -m pip -V

pip 9.0.1 from /Users/lev/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

You probably have a mismatch between those versions.

Comment: Here's what I get when I run pip- V : pip 21.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9).                                                                                                     And what I get when I run python -m pip -V : /Users/me/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Comment: Change you pycharm's python interpreter to `python3.7` and then your packages will be detected. Alternatively you can install your packages with: `python2 -m pip install ...` but using python2 is discouraged.

Comment: I have added your solution in the question. Please have a look.